# Uncaught TypeError: h.forEach is not a function D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create a Chord chart in viz.js / d3.js and I take the date (an array of array) from my webservice with an ajax fuction:

```
$.ajax({
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:9000/D_tre",
  "method": "GET",
  "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  "success": function(data) {
    //grafico_d_tre(pos_data); 
    pos_data = data;
    grafico(pos_data);
  },
  error: function (result) {
  }
});
```

I call the function `grafico()` in my ajax that takes the data and creates the chart:

```
function grafico(pos_data) {

  console.log(pos_data);
  var colors = {
    "BA": "#da4480",
    "Avventura": "#5ab449",
    "Fantasy e per bambini": "#7f5acd",
    "Giallo": "#aab740",
    "Romanzo": "#ce58c0",
    "Sport": "#50a26e",
    "Storia e Letteratura": "#45c0bc",
    "BT": "#ce5929", "FG": "#4e7bda",
    "LE": "#d49d3c",
    "TA": "#6660a3"
  };

  var sortOrder = [
    "BA",
    "Avventura",
    "Fantasy e per bambini",
    "Giallo",
    "Romanzo",
    "Sport",
    "Storia e Letteratura",
    "BT",
    "FG",
    "LE",
    "TA"
  ];

  function sort(a,b){
    return d3.ascending(sortOrder.indexOf(a),sortOrder.indexOf(b));
  }

  var format = d3.format(".3s"); 
  var ch = viz.ch()
    .data(pos_data)
    .padding(.01)
    .sort(sort)
    .innerRadius(430)
    .outerRadius(450)
    .duration(1000)
    .chordOpacity(0.3)
    .labelPadding(.03)
    .valueFormat(function(d){return d3.format("")(d);}) //format numeri
    .fill(function(d){ return colors[d];});

  var width=1200, height=1100;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height",height).attr("width",width);

  svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(600,550)").call(ch);

  // adjust height of frame in bl.ocks.org
  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height+"px").style("width", width+"px");  
}
```

The ajax function is a success and returns my structure:

```
[['BA','Avventura','3340']
,['Avventura','BA','3340']
,['BA','Fantasy e per bambini','137']
,['Fantasy e per bambini','BA','137']
,['BA','Giallo','25']
,['Giallo','BA','25']
,['BA','Romanzo','542']
,['Romanzo','BA','542']
,['BA','Sport','127']
,['Sport','BA','127']
,['BA','Storia e Letteratura','54']
,['Storia e Letteratura','BA','54']
,['BT','Avventura','7']
,['Avventura','BT','7']
,['BT','Romanzo','32']
,['Romanzo','BT','32']
,['BT','Storia e Letteratura','4']
,['Storia e Letteratura','BT','4']
,['FG','Avventura','196']
,['Avventura','FG','196']
,['FG','Fantasy e per bambini','8']
,['Fantasy e per bambini','FG','8']
,['FG','Giallo','2']
,['Giallo','FG','2']
,['FG','Romanzo','89']
,['Romanzo','FG','89']
,['FG','Sport','10']
,['Sport','FG','10']
,['FG','Storia e Letteratura','2']
,['Storia e Letteratura','FG','2']
,['LE','Avventura','286']
,['Avventura','LE','286']
,['LE','Fantasy e per bambini','13']
,['Fantasy e per bambini','LE','13']
,['LE','Giallo','8']
,['Giallo','LE','8']
,['LE','Romanzo','17']
,['Romanzo','LE','17']
,['LE','Sport','15']
,['Sport','LE','15']
,['LE','Storia e Letteratura','7']
,['Storia e Letteratura','LE','7']
,['TA','Avventura','190']
,['Avventura','TA','190']
,['TA','Fantasy e per bambini','16']
,['Fantasy e per bambini','TA','16']
,['TA','Giallo','0']
,['Giallo','TA','0']
,['TA','Romanzo','27']
,['Romanzo','TA','27']
,['TA','Sport','29']
,['Sport','TA','29']
,['TA','Storia e Letteratura','7']
,['Storia e Letteratura','TA','7']
]
```

But I get the following error in my console:

> "Uncaught TypeError: h.forEach is not a function"

and the chart doesn't start. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Can you show the code that contains this snippet (`h.forEach`)?

Comment: I'm searching too

Comment: he come from viz.v1.1.0.min.js that is a d3 library :(

Comment: you can find it here [http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js]

Comment: not working your file

Comment: http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js

Comment: @Mozzer you are using http://vizjs.org/ so maybe that is what you have the problem with and that is the library you have posted a link to.. there is two functions h.foreach functions in the library but I suspect that there is something in your code that is causing the error.

```h.forEach(function (t) {
}), h.forEach(function (t) {
```

Comment: @Mozzer What version of D3 are you on? The version 1.1.0 of viz.js you linked to still requires D3 v3. If you are already using D3 v4 this might cause these issues.